# what is the best way to install ros on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I tried installing ros on ubuntu 12.10 but the normal method doesn't work (i tried desktop and desktop-full). Has anyone installed ros on ubuntu 12.10. I saw some questions but i'm new to ubuntu and linux so those answers were a bit advanced for me.

Also when will groovy be released ? I thought it was nov 15. Should I just try installing the groovy barebones/stack instead ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48399/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-12.10/) by [canatan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3563/canatan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EDIT:
official repositories out (compiled for ubuntu 12.10 and 64 bits only as of 19 nov):
You can follow the installation instructions here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation

Old answer:

> Actually, ROS is already ready for
> Ubuntu 12.10 via apt-get install. You
> just need to use the following
> repository:
>
> `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb
> http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu
> quantal main" >
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'`
>
> and then do
>
> `sudo apt-get update`
>
> and install ros and your favourite
> stacks with
>
> `sudo apt-get install
> ros-groovy-STACKNAME`
>
> Hope this helps, remember to switch
> back to the main repository in some
> days when the official version is
> ready. The repository I gave your is
> not the main one.

---

Originally posted by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) with karma: 483 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
This will install groovy which is not even beta at the moment and it is still changing a lot. I really would not suggest to use it yet.

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2012-11-15**:
It has been tested in my robotics lab and works perfectly as of today. Moreover, release date is today, I hardly doubt that it will change a lot.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-15**:
The ROS developers are close to releasing the first beta release but I would not expect a final release before December. At the moment, 32 bit packages for 12.10 are not even built. [Related post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/17023/match=) on ros-users.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Groovy is not really ready for use yet. In particular when you are new to ROS, you will run into many problems. The only way to get ROS on 12.10 is compiling it from source at the moment which is also not completely trivial since you might run into different compile problems caused by newer library versions in Ubuntu.

The easiest solution is probably to install Ubuntu 12.04.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1